# "git clone" is not working when i try to clone a repo on my pc

Tags: git, github

I am having issues with cloning repos.

I enter

$ git clone https://github.com/username/myrepo

Cloning into "myrepo" ...

and then nothing happens.

I believe it happened after I installed Dockertools and localstack. Not sure what has changed

Comment: you must add .git at the end of url.

Comment: @pkeu That's not a requirement.

Comment: @chepner thanks, learned something new!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following steps for `git clone`

1. Visit your repository on github
2. Copy the https link from the repository as shown in the image below

[image: git clone]

3. Run command `git clone https-link`

This will clone the git repo to your folder where you executed that command

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem. In my case **public repos** are cloning correctly but for **private repos** it only showed "**Cloning into [projectName]**" but nothing happened.

Solution was: I just **added SSH key** to my bitbucket setting.

Here is 2 URL I followed.

[Tutorial Doc](https://syntaxbytetutorials.com/add-a-github-ssh-key-on-windows/)

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgZIv5HI44o)

After this your problem should be solve if it hung for private repo.